# Why cap does not print the length of the underlying array?

Tags: arrays, go, slice

I am reading the A Tour of GO, in the [Slice length and capacity](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/11) section, I ran the example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    s := []int{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13}
    printSlice(s)

    // Slice the slice to give it zero length.
    s = s[:0]
    printSlice(s)

    // Extend its length.
    s = s[:4]
    printSlice(s)

    // Drop its first two values.
    s = s[2:]
    printSlice(s)
}

func printSlice(s []int) {
    fmt.Printf("len=%d cap=%d %v\n", len(s), cap(s), s)
}
```

When I build the app and run it, it prints like this:

```
len=6 cap=6 [2 3 5 7 11 13]
len=0 cap=6 []
len=4 cap=6 [2 3 5 7]
len=2 cap=4 [5 7]
```

In the Go docs, the **cap** is the length of the underlying array, why it's value is not 6?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> In the Go docs, the **cap** is the length of the underlying array, why it's value is not 6?

Because the capacity is **not** the size of the backing array (there may be special cases when they are equal, but in general they are not). When a slice is created by slicing a backing array, using `0` for the low index (or omitting it), and the array length for the high index (or omitting it), then yes, the capacity will be equal to the array's length.

[Spec: Length and capacity:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Length_and_capacity)

> The capacity of a slice is the number of elements for which there is space allocated in the underlying array.

So the capacity starts at the first element of the slice, and if that is not the same as the first element of the backing array, they won't be equal. This is also stated explicitly in the [Tour page](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/11) you linked:

> The capacity of a slice is the number of elements in the underlying array, **counting from the first element in the slice**.

There is also a [full slice expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) which has the form of:

```
a[low : high : max]
```

Where you can control the resulting slice's capacity, you can limit how far future slicing may extend the slice. The `max` index may point to an element *before* the last element of the array.

See this example:

```
a := [10]int{}

s := a[:] // len=10, cap=10
fmt.Printf("len=%d, cap=%d\n", len(s), cap(s))

s = a[2:] // len=8, cap=8
fmt.Printf("len=%d, cap=%d\n", len(s), cap(s))

s = a[2:7] // len=5, cap=8
fmt.Printf("len=%d, cap=%d\n", len(s), cap(s))

s = a[2:7:8] // len=5, cap=6
fmt.Printf("len=%d, cap=%d\n", len(s), cap(s))
```

Outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/LtvU96mRRWL)):

```
len=10, cap=10
len=8, cap=8
len=5, cap=8
len=5, cap=6
```

Answer (score 1):

When you drop the two first values, you stay with just the last 4 remaining items in the underlying array.

`[2 3 5 7 11 13]`

When you do `s = [:0]` the slice will have length 0 and cap 6: `[]2 3 5 7 11 13`

When you do `s = [:4]` the slice will have length 4 and cap 6: `[2 3 5 7] 11 13`

When you do `s = [2:]` the slice will have length 2 and cap 4: `2 3 [5 7] 11 13`

This is because that array has no access to the first two values anymore while the last two can still be accessed if the length of the slice is extended.